# SQL N items per Group in SQL || SQL Sub Query Limit

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to Select join with `cats` table with `data`. Join with `cats.id = data.cat_id`. with limit 3 `data` table row for each unique category id `cat.id`

Table: `cats`

```text
id | parent_id | name
---+-----------+--------
1  | 0         | Games
2  | 0         | Music
3  | 0         | Apps
```

Table:`data`

```text
--------------------------
id |  cat_id |  data
---+---------+------------
1  |  1      |  Cat1 Data1
2  |  1      |  Cat1 Data2
3  |  1      |  Cat1 Data3
4  |  1      |  Cat1 Data4
---+---------+------------
5  |  2      |  Cat2 Data1
6  |  2      |  Cat2 Data2
7  |  2      |  Cat2 Data3
8  |  2      |  Cat3 Data4
---+---------+------------
9  |  3      |  Cat3 Data1
10 |  3      |  Cat3 Data2
11 |  3      |  Cat3 Data3
12 |  3      |  Cat3 Data4
```

I want like bellow. For one `cats` per row select three `data` row select.

```text
category  | data
----------+------------
Games     | Cat1 Data1
Games     | Cat1 Data2
Games     | Cat1 Data3
----------+------------
Music     | Cat2 Data1
Music     | Cat2 Data2
Music     | Cat2 Data3
----------+------------
Apps      | Cat3 Data1
Apps      | Cat3 Data2
Apps      | Cat3 Data3
```

if this not posiable `group_concat` with `,` also work for me. I will split it with php.

```text
cat_name  |  data
----------+-------------------------------------
Book      | Cat1 Data1, Cat1 Data2, Cat1 Data3
Music     | Cat2 Data1, Cat2 Data2, Cat2 Data3
Game      | Cat3 Data1, Cat3 Data2, Cat3 Data3
```

Comment: Which is the engine (mysql or sql-server)?

Comment: It is difficult to understand exactly what you want, but it seems like you could accomplish what you want to do by using `UNION` on multiple queries while limiting each of those queries to the top 3 items.

Comment: mysql And xampp
I Develop a php application

Comment: I Want to select 5 category items and groupconat 3 data table column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this solve your

```sql
SELECT
    sq.category,
    sq.data
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATA.*,
        cats.name AS category,
        row_number() over(PARTITION BY cat_id ORDER BY cat_id DESC) AS ROW_COUNT FROM `data`
    INNER JOIN cats ON data.cat_id = cats.id
    ) AS sq
WHERE
    ROW_COUNT <= 3
```

here in the query ... ... ROW_COUNT <= **3** you may set limit for selection.